# LinearInterpolation not working with transform in DataFrames.jl

Tags: dataframe, julia, interpolation

I have defined the following linear interpolator:

```
julia> using DataFrames, Interpolations

julia> xs = 1:0.2:5;

julia> ys = log.(xs);

julia> li = LinearInterpolation(xs, ys);
```

and have a data frame:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(x=2:0.1:3)
11×1 DataFrame
 Row │ x
     │ Float64
─────┼─────────
   1 │     2.0
   2 │     2.1
   3 │     2.2
   4 │     2.3
   5 │     2.4
   6 │     2.5
   7 │     2.6
   8 │     2.7
   9 │     2.8
  10 │     2.9
  11 │     3.0
```

I can pass the `:x` column of a data frame to `li` like this:

```
julia> li(df.x)
11-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.6931471805599453
 0.7408022704621078
 0.7884573603642704
 0.831963048859085
 0.8754687373538997
 0.915490091190668
 0.9555114450274363
 0.9925654311042973
 1.0296194171811581
 1.0641158529246337
 1.0986122886681098
```

However, when I try using the `transform` function it fails:

```
julia> transform(df, :x => li => :y)
ERROR: ArgumentError: Unrecognized column selector: :x => (21-element extrapolate(scale(interpolate(::Vector{Float64}, BSpline(Linear())), (1.0:0.2:5.0,)), Throw()) with element type Float64:
```

and throws a strange error that I do not understand. How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

The problem you encounter is that `li` is not defined by LinearInterpolations.jl to have a type that is a subtype of `Function`:

```
julia> li isa Function
false
```

Objects such as `li` are called [functors](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/methods/#Function-like-objects) in Julia and sometimes their authors do not opt-in for making them a subtype of `Function`. In such a case the simplest solution is to use an anonymous function as a work-around:

```
julia> transform(df, :x => (x -> li(x)) => :y)
11×2 DataFrame
 Row │ x        y
     │ Float64  Float64
─────┼───────────────────
   1 │     2.0  0.693147
   2 │     2.1  0.740802
   3 │     2.2  0.788457
   4 │     2.3  0.831963
   5 │     2.4  0.875469
   6 │     2.5  0.91549
   7 │     2.6  0.955511
   8 │     2.7  0.992565
   9 │     2.8  1.02962
  10 │     2.9  1.06412
  11 │     3.0  1.09861
```